# Git Versioning New Approach

Tags: git, branch, gitversion

I am trying to automatize Nuget Versioning on my project. I am using VSTS for CI/CD layer. I work alone. At the same time with the project I want to catch the git's secrets.

I tried Git Flow standarts but it didn't satisfy my needs.

The flow in my mind is that: there will be only 2 branch, Master branch will be permanent, other branch will be Temporary. I ll delete temporary branch when I merge it to master. To fix bugs and increment patch version I'll directly commit the changes to master branch. To increment minor version I'll use branch strategy. For major changes I want to use the GitVersion (Writing +semver: major to commit message [Source1](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/))

For my needs I tried to use GitVersion ([Source](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/#gitflow-examples)) . It uses SemVer. And I couldn't set the GitVersion.yml file according to my needs.

Do you know any way to achieve my goals or GitVersion configuration settings?

The picture is below is visualization of my needs.

[image]

Comment: By the way i don't prefer tagging. I ll tag once and GitVersion handle the versioning.

Comment: That's not possible to do it without tagging because semantic versioning has a human meaning (depending if changes are breaking or bug fix). So GitVersion can't handle everything for you...